# SQLAlchemy Query Concatenation

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, text, sqlalchemy

This is the first time to use SQLAlchemy. I am trying to concatenate a variable to Sqlalchemy text as follows:

```
input_sp = os.environ.get("STORED_PROC")

stament_exec = text("""EXEC""") + input_sp + text("""dbo.myStoredprocedure @id = :id , @name = :name """)
```

I am trying to understand if this is the right way to do the concatenation of SQL query execution of a stored procedure based on environment variable that is getting passed for name of stored procedure

Comment: `TextClause` instances (returned by `text()`) don't support addition; it would be easier to build the query string first and then call `text()` on it.